# How to use media queries in flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, media-queries

I'm using flexbox to do the layout of my website to facilitate the responsiveness but when the width of the screen gets to less than 800px, rows get on top of each other. I'm trying to solve this with media queries but don't know exactly what to do here. I've tried using `flex-shrink` but I'm not sure how to use it as well. Can anyone help me with this?

I'm putting here the whole code for the page that I've done so far.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>A.J. Machado</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Joana Oliveira" />
    <link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One|Amiri|Prata|Lato:300|Cormorant+Garamond|Francois+One|Inter|Josefin+Sans:100|Montserrat|Playfair+Display|Ibarra+Real+Nova:400,700|Sen:700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/db04c17f0a.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrap-container">
      <header>
        <div class="row header-container-2">
          <div class="row header">
            <div class="logo">
              <h1>
                ana <br />
                joão
              </h1>
            </div>

            <div>
              <nav>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="transition" href="link">home</a></li>
                  <li><a class="transition" href="./about.html">about</a></li>
                  <li><a class="transition" href="link">work</a></li>
                  <li>
                    <a class="transition" href="./contact.html">contact</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a class="transition" href="./shop.html">shop</a></li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row section-1-about">
            <div class="welcome-section">
              <h1>
                Find magic in the <br />
                smallest of things.
              </h1>
              <div class="intro-text">
                I’m Ana and I will help you with any design solution you might
                be looking for. I'll build the identity of your new, creative
                and exciting projects and restore ones that already exist.
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="picture">
              <img src="sunset-flower.jpg" max-width="800" height="550" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>
        <main>
        <div class="section-1b-about"></div>
        <div class="row section-2-about">
                <div>
                  <img
                    src="bookpicture.png"
                    class="bookpicture"
                    max-width="800"
                    height="600"
                  />
                </div>

                <div class="about-me">
                  <div><h1 class="about-me-title">About me</h1></div>
                  <div class="about-me-text">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean
                    commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque
                    penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
                    mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
                    quis, sem.
                    <p>
                      Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla
                      vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus
                      ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis
                      eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.
                    </p>
                    Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus.
                    Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac,
                    enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a,
                    tellus.
                  </div>
                  <div class="row inquire-about">
                        <a class="connect-button-about" href="./contact.html">Let's connect</a>
                      </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row section-3-about"></div>
              <div class="row section-4-about">
                <div class="column connect">
                  <div class="connect-title">
                    <h3>CONNECT</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="work-together">
                    Still here? I would love <br />
                    to hear you story!
                  </div>
                  <div class="connect-text">
                    Tell me your story and how you business begun, <br />
                    I would love to hear and help you achieve your goals.
                  </div>
                  <div class="row inquire">
                    <a class="connect-button" href="./contact.html">Get in touch</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="row section-5-about"></div>
        </main>
        <footer class="footer">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="column">
                    <div class="logo-footer">
                      <h1>
                        ana <br />
                        joão
                      </h1>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="column">
                    <div class="menu-footer">
                      <li><a class="transition" href="link">home</a></li>
                      <li><a class="transition" href="./about.html">about</a></li>
                      <li><a class="transition" href="link">work</a></li>
                      <li>
                        <a class="transition" href="./contact.html">contact</a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a class="transition" href="./shop.html">shop</a></li>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="column">
                    <div class="social-media">
                      <ul>
                        <li><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></li>
                        <li><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></li>
                        <li><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row rights">
                    <h3>Joana Oliveira© All Rights Reserved</h3>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

css

```
body {
  padding: 0;
}
* {
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*--------rows----------*/
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

/*-------columns-------*/
.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}

/*--------------------HEADER---------------------*/

.header-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 370px;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: rgba(234, 203, 193, 0.4);
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 200px;
}

.logo {
  font-family: "Francois One", sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  padding-left: 80px;
}

.header {
  height: 280px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
/* ------- nav --------- */

nav {
  height: 50px;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px 50px 0 0;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
}
nav li {
  margin-left: 45px;
  font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
  display: list-item;
}

nav a {
  color: #343335;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* ------- Containers --------- */

.wrap-container {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.welcome-section {
  width: 400px; 
}

.welcome-section h1 {
  font-family: "Ibarra Real Nova", serif;
  font-size: 50px;
}
.intro-text {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.8;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.work-together {
  font-family: "Ibarra Real Nova", serif;
  align-items: center;
  color: rgba(40, 44, 48, 1);
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-top: 180px;
}

.connect-title {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  line-height: 1.8;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-left: 200px;
}

.connect-text {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  color: rgba(40, 44, 48, 1);
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 30px 0 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.4;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}
.inquire {
  justify-content: center;
}
.connect-button {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  color: rgba(198, 211, 222, 1);
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(48, 51, 54);
  padding: 10px 17px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: inherit;
}



/* ------- FOOTER --------- */

.footer {
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #3d3d3d;
}

.logo-footer h1 {
  font-family: "Francois One", sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 20px 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu-footer {
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.menu-footer ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}
.menu-footer li {
  margin-left: 45px;
  font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
  display: list-item;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
}

.menu-footer a {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.social-media ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.social-media li {
  margin-left: 30px;
  display: list-item;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 40px 0 10px 0;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.rights {
  padding-top: 30px;
  justify-content: center;
}
.rights h3 {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

/* ---------------- ABOUT PAGE---------------- */

.header-container-2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 370px;
  background-color: rgba(221, 226, 220, 1);
  display: flex;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.section-1-about {
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.section-1b-about {
  height: 550px;
}

.section-2-about {
  height: 800px;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgba(234, 203, 193, 0.3);
}

.bookpicture {
  padding: 50px 50px 0 0;
}

.about-me-title {
  font-family: "Ibarra Real Nova", serif;
  align-items: center;
  color: rgba(40, 44, 48, 1);
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 250px 0 0 50px;
}

.about-me-text {
  width: 400px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.8;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.connect-button-about {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  color: rgba(198, 211, 222, 1);
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(48, 51, 54);
  padding: 10px 17px;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: inherit;
}

.section-3-about {
  height: 200px;
}

.section-4-about {
  background-color: rgba(198, 211, 222, 1);
  height: 300px;
}

.inquire-about {
  padding: 20px 0 0 50px;
}

.section-5-about {
  height: 300px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/joanaoli09/pen/YzXoEmm

As you're not going to be able to see how it looks because of the images, here is what it looks like:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe change layout to `flex-direction:column` when the screen is too narrow ?

Comment: I did that but nothing seems to change for some reason. Not sure if I' writing the code correctly : ```@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .wrap-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  } ```

Answer (score 1):

You want `flex-direction: column`:

```css
.flex{display:flex}

.flex.m{
    flex-direction:column
}
```

```html
<h3>I'm desktop</h3>
<div class="d flex">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
</div>

<h3>I'm mobile</h3>
<div class="m flex">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
</div>
```